# load ListView in fragment from mysql

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-asynctask, fragment

I am trying to generate a listview in a fragment. The code show no error but when i try to start the application, after the progressdialog show then the application crashed.below is my HomeFragment.java file. Please help. Im a newbie in android development.

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment  {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser2 jParser = new JSONParser2();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    //@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_products,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        initControls();
    }
        //@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
        public void initControls(){             

        //testing
     //  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
     //   {
     //   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
     //   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    //   }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
           }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            getActivity().finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog;
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

the logcat i get:

```
04-20 00:04:09.071: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 00:04:09.251: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 00:04:09.331: D/All Products:(1257): {"success":1,"products":[{"created_at":"2015-04-15 21:52:09","pid":"1","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"1111.00","description":"good","name":"iphone "},{"created_at":"2015-04-18 02:41:49","pid":"13","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"25.00","description":"cheap\n\n","name":"Samsung "},{"created_at":"2015-04-18 03:26:40","pid":"14","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"1000.00","description":"bad\n","name":"xiaomi"}]}
04-20 00:04:09.391: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 00:04:09.451: D/AndroidRuntime(1257): Shutting down VM
04-20 00:04:09.451: W/dalvikvm(1257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a26ba8)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): Process: mygp.gptrade, PID: 1257
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at mygp.gptrade.HomeFragment$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:200)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at mygp.gptrade.HomeFragment$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:1)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-20 00:04:09.551: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 00:04:16.831: I/Process(1257): Sending signal. PID: 1257 SIG: 9
```

tknell :
the logcat i get for 2nd error.

```
    04-20 05:01:19.800: D/All Products:(1039): {"success":1,"products":[{"created_at":"2015-04-15 21:52:09","
    pid":"1","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"1111.00","description":"good","name":"iphone "},{"created_at":"2015-04-18 02:41:49","
    pid":"13","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"25.00","description":"cheap\n\n","name":"Samsung "},{"created_at":"2015-04-18 03:26:40","pid":"14","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"1000.00","description":"bad\n","name":"xiaomi"}]}
04-20 05:01:20.060: I/Choreographer(1039): Skipped 142 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 05:01:20.560: I/Choreographer(1039): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 05:01:27.370: I/Choreographer(1039): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 05:01:29.990: D/dalvikvm(1039): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 301K, 10% free 3623K/3992K, paused 351ms, total 360ms
04-20 05:01:30.760: I/Choreographer(1039): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 05:01:32.810: D/AndroidRuntime(1039): Shutting down VM
04-20 05:01:32.810: W/dalvikvm(1039): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a26ba8)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): Process: mygp.gptrade, PID: 1039
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at         org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at mygp.gptrade.JSONParser2.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser2.java:62)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at mygp.gptrade.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditProductActivity.java:131)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-20 05:01:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EditProductActivity.java

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

`EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser2 jsonParser2 = new JSONParser2();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}`

}

3rd logcat
(without runOnUiThread)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity mygp.gptrade.EditProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2e99188 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-320,96} that was originally added here
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at mygp.gptrade.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails.onPreExecute(EditProductActivity.java:111)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at mygp.gptrade.EditProductActivity.onCreate(EditProductActivity.java:72)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-21 04:34:25.747: E/WindowManager(1154):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You can't use Intent in your doInbackground

Comment: when i do this in activity, there is no problem. when move it to fragment then cant d.

Comment: getActivity().getApplicationContext() change this to getActivity(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the member `pDialog` and use it to dismiss the dialog in the `onPostExecute` method, but in the `onPreExecute` method you declare another `pDialog` variable that holds the created dialog instead of your member. Because of that, when you try to dismiss the dialog, the member variable `pDialog` is null.

To fix that, remove the other `pDialog` variable in the `onPreExecute`:

old:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

new:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: when i clicked the item on the list, it crashed too. is it problem with the intent?

Comment: In your `EditProductActivity.java` line 131 (GetProductDetails.run) you access the network in the UI Thread (without AsyncTask). That is not allowed in Android and that's why it crashes.

Comment: i add the editProductActivity.java
i try remove the runOnUiThread but it still crashed.

Comment: Its below the 2nd logcat. Sorry for the mess, im dunno how to edit it.

Comment: But without the runOnUiThread the error message should be different, can you post that error log, too?

Comment: can u help me on this?

Comment: I don't see a crash in the  3rd log, the "has leaked window" message should not be the cause of the crash. Maybe try to post a new Question with the current problem, this thread gets pretty confusing with all this logs :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793846/onitemclicked-from-fragment-to-activity

Comment: i posted the new question.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in to your postExecute method

```
 if (success == 1) {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                productsList.add(map);
            }
        } else {
            // no products found
            // Launch Add New product Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    NewProductActivity.class);
            // Closing all previous activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```