# onItemClicked from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemclick, android-runonuithread

i have a listView of item in a fragment. when i click one of the item, it will open another activity and show the details of the item. but when the progress bar is loading then the whole app crashed.

EditProductActivity.java

```
public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser2 jsonParser2 = new JSONParser2();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://gemini888.tk/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

just made a proper alignment

the logcat:

```
04-22 05:41:18.881: D/All Products:(1262): {"success":1,"products":    [{"created_at":"2015-04-15 21:52:09","pid":"1","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"1111.00","description":"good","name":"iphone "},{"created_at":"2015-04-18 02:41:49","pid":"13","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"60.00","description":"cheapo","name":"Samsung "},{"created_at":"2015-04-18 03:26:40","pid":"14","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"1000.00","description":"bad\n","name":"xiaomi"},{"created_at":"2015-04-21 05:56:55","pid":"15","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"500.00","description":"new","name":"Acer "},{"created_at":"2015-04-22 02:58:09","pid":"16","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"500.00","description":"??\n\n","name":"??"}]}
04-22 05:41:35.551: D/dalvikvm(1262): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 253K, 9% free 3667K/3992K, paused 383ms, total 393ms
04-22 05:41:39.991: D/AndroidRuntime(1262): Shutting down VM
04-22 05:41:39.991: W/dalvikvm(1262): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a54ba8)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): Process: mygp.gptrade, PID: 1262
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at mygp.gptrade.JSONParser2.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser2.java:62)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at mygp.gptrade.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditProductActivity.java:131)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 05:41:40.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 05:41:47.031: I/Process(1262): Sending signal. PID: 1262 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post some logs please

Comment: Sorry I haven't read your code only the question. My advice is use something like eventbus. I do it and I'm happing now, no coupling between components anymore ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing `runOnUiThread` in the `doInBackground` method of `GetProductDetails`. The method is specifically there to do long running operation off the main UI thread. If you want to update the UI then do it in `onPostExecute`

Make the following change

```
 /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        JSONObject json = null;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (json != null) {
                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    // product with this pid found
                    // Edit Text
                    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                    txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                    txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                    // display product data in EditText
                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                } else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: then what should i change? i tried move the runOnUiThread to onPostExecute, but still crashed.

Comment: pls help me on this.. im new to android

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem.
i add this code in `onCreate`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
       }
```

Comment: This is not the correct way. You are now forcing your code to run on the main thread.

Comment: Check the edited answer, I have added the changes that you need to make in your `GetProductDetails` AsyncTask